# Why eureka considers a service still 'UP' even if its last renewal time was two days ago

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, service-discovery

I have a service with 2 replicas running. But I found the service having 3 **UP** instances in eureka's dashboard.

Below the detail info of the service in eureka. The problematic instance is **8d0c39f3ed9b:ocr-server:8095**, whose last renewal time was two days ago. And the status and health url can NOT be accessed. I'm wondering why eureka considers it's UP!

```
<application>
<name>OCR-SERVER</name>
<instance>
<instanceId>211a4634b45f:ocr-server:8095</instanceId>
<hostName>211a4634b45f</hostName>
<app>OCR-SERVER</app>
<ipAddr>10.0.0.38</ipAddr>
<status>UP</status>
<overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
<port enabled="true">8095</port>
<securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
<countryId>1</countryId>
<dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
<name>MyOwn</name>
</dataCenterInfo>
<leaseInfo>
<renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
<durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
<registrationTimestamp>1505589414444</registrationTimestamp>
<lastRenewalTimestamp>1505833520772</lastRenewalTimestamp>
<evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
<serviceUpTimestamp>1505589414444</serviceUpTimestamp>
</leaseInfo>
<metadata class="java.util.Collections$EmptyMap"/>
<homePageUrl>http://211a4634b45f:8095/</homePageUrl>
<statusPageUrl>http://211a4634b45f:8096/manage/info</statusPageUrl>
<healthCheckUrl>http://211a4634b45f:8096/manage/health</healthCheckUrl>
<vipAddress>ocr-server</vipAddress>
<secureVipAddress>ocr-server</secureVipAddress>
<isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
<lastUpdatedTimestamp>1505589414444</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
<lastDirtyTimestamp>1505589412731</lastDirtyTimestamp>
<actionType>ADDED</actionType>
</instance>
<instance>
<instanceId>8d0c39f3ed9b:ocr-server:8095</instanceId>
<hostName>8d0c39f3ed9b</hostName>
<app>OCR-SERVER</app>
<ipAddr>10.0.0.38</ipAddr>
<status>UP</status>
<overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
<port enabled="true">8095</port>
<securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
<countryId>1</countryId>
<dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
<name>MyOwn</name>
</dataCenterInfo>
<leaseInfo>
<renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
<durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
<registrationTimestamp>1505589356797</registrationTimestamp>
<lastRenewalTimestamp>1505589356797</lastRenewalTimestamp>
<evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
<serviceUpTimestamp>1505589356797</serviceUpTimestamp>
</leaseInfo>
<metadata class="java.util.Collections$EmptyMap"/>
<homePageUrl>http://8d0c39f3ed9b:8095/</homePageUrl>
<statusPageUrl>http://8d0c39f3ed9b:8096/manage/info</statusPageUrl>
<healthCheckUrl>http://8d0c39f3ed9b:8096/manage/health</healthCheckUrl>
<vipAddress>ocr-server</vipAddress>
<secureVipAddress>ocr-server</secureVipAddress>
<isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
<lastUpdatedTimestamp>1505589356797</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
<lastDirtyTimestamp>1505589356787</lastDirtyTimestamp>
<actionType>ADDED</actionType>
</instance>
<instance>
<instanceId>0c62739f5ca8:ocr-server:8095</instanceId>
<hostName>0c62739f5ca8</hostName>
<app>OCR-SERVER</app>
<ipAddr>10.0.0.34</ipAddr>
<status>UP</status>
<overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
<port enabled="true">8095</port>
<securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
<countryId>1</countryId>
<dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
<name>MyOwn</name>
</dataCenterInfo>
<leaseInfo>
<renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
<durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
<registrationTimestamp>1505589403150</registrationTimestamp>
<lastRenewalTimestamp>1505833509700</lastRenewalTimestamp>
<evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
<serviceUpTimestamp>1505589403150</serviceUpTimestamp>
</leaseInfo>
<metadata class="java.util.Collections$EmptyMap"/>
<homePageUrl>http://0c62739f5ca8:8095/</homePageUrl>
<statusPageUrl>http://0c62739f5ca8:8096/manage/info</statusPageUrl>
<healthCheckUrl>http://0c62739f5ca8:8096/manage/health</healthCheckUrl>
<vipAddress>ocr-server</vipAddress>
<secureVipAddress>ocr-server</secureVipAddress>
<isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
<lastUpdatedTimestamp>1505589403150</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
<lastDirtyTimestamp>1505589400020</lastDirtyTimestamp>
<actionType>ADDED</actionType>
</instance>
</application>
```

The config of eureka client looks like below,

```
eureka:
  instance:
    statusPageUrlPath: /info
    healthCheckUrlPath: /health
    preferIpAddress: false
  client:
    fetchRegistry: true
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-peer1:8761/eureka,http://eureka-peer2:8761/eureka
```

The configuration of eureka server is,

```
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    enableSelfPreservation: false
    homePageUrl: http://${eureka.hostname}/
---
spring:
  profiles: peer1
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-peer1
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-peer2:${server.port}/eureka/

---
spring:
  profiles: peer2
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-peer2
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-peer1:${server.port}/eureka/
```

And both the eureka clients and servers are running in docker swarm.

Comment: enableSelfPreservation: false

Comment: @spencergibb, I already configured `enableSelfPreservation: false` in eureka server. Do you mean this option also impact the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server has probably entered the self preservation mode, that's why you see a stale instance there.

I see you have the `enableSelfPreservation: false` option however it is not in the right section, it should be `eureka.server.enableSelfPreservation`, your entry is under `eureka.instance.enableSelfPreservation` which is not right.